# Implement predicate chaining based on different types

Tags: java, java-8

I'm searching for an ability to chain Predicates and test them together.

**Thoughts**

We have conditions for predicates(or else) :

```
 1. P<T>, P<R>, P<S>
 2. P<T>.and(P<T>) => P<T> as result P<T>.test(t1, t2)
 3. P<T>.and(P<R>) => P<T,R> as result P<T,R>.test(t,r)
 4. P<T>.and(P<R>.or(P<S>)) => P<T,R,S> as result P<T,R,S>.test(t,r,s)
```

I have the models

```
class User {
            private String name;
            private boolean isActive;
            public User(String name, boolean isActive) {
                this.name = name;
                this.isActive = isActive;
            }
            //getters only...
        }
```

Order

```
public class Order {
        private long createdAt;
        private User user;
        private Manager manager;
        private boolean isApproved;
    
        public Order(User user, Manager manager, long createdAt, boolean isApproved) {
            this.user = user;
            this.manager = manager;
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
            this.isApproved = isApproved;
        }
        // getters only ...
    }
```

Manager

```
class Manager {
        private ManagerCompetency competency;
        private String name;
        public Manager(String name, ManagerCompetency competency) {
            this.name = name;
            this.competency = competency;
        }
        //getters only...
    }
```

As result, I need something like
for short OrderAcceptanceSpecification OAS

```
Boolean result = OAS.isUserCanCreateOrder()
                 .and(OAS.isOrderApproved())
                 .and(OAS.isOrderExpiredAfter(3600)).negate()
                 .and(
                     OAS.isOrderApproverCompetentAs(Competencies.HIGH)
                     .or(OAS.isOrderApproverCompetentAs(Competencies.MIDDLE)
                 ).test(Order, Manager, User)
```

Any suggestions/improvements are welcome.

I have found a similar solution

```
public class ChainedPredicate<T> {

    private T t;

    private Predicate<T> predicate;

    public ChainedPredicate(T t, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(t);
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
        this.t = t;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    private ChainedPredicate(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public Predicate<T> toPredicate() {
        return t -> test();
    }

    public boolean test() {
        return predicate.test(t);
    }

    public ChainedPredicate<T> and(ChainedPredicate<?> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return new ChainedPredicate<T>(t -> test() && other.test());
    }

    public ChainedPredicate<T> or(ChainedPredicate<?> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return new ChainedPredicate<T>(t -> test() || other.test());
    }

    public ChainedPredicate<T> negate() {
        return new ChainedPredicate<T>(toPredicate().negate());
    }
}
```

Perform testing

```
public class TestChainedPredicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Predicate<Boolean> tp1 = x -> 1 >0;
        Predicate<String> fp1 = x -> 1 <0;
        Predicate<Integer> fp2 = x -> 1 <0;

        ChainedPredicate<Boolean> p = new ChainedPredicate<Boolean>(true, tp1); //true
        ChainedPredicate<String> p1 = new ChainedPredicate<String>("123", fp1); // false
        ChainedPredicate<Integer> p2 = new ChainedPredicate<Integer>(100, fp2); // false

        boolean result = p.and(p1.or(p2)).test(); // false
        System.out.println(result + " expected : " + false + " : " + ((result==false) ? "OK" : "ERROR") );

        result = p.or(p1.or(p2)).test();
        System.out.println(result + " expected : " + true + " : " + ((result==true) ? "OK" : "ERROR"));

        result = p1.or(p.and(p2)).test();
        System.out.println(result + " expected : " + false + " : " + ((result==false) ? "OK" : "ERROR"));

        result = p1.or(p.or(p2)).test(); // false
        System.out.println(result + " expected : " + true + " : " + ((result==true) ? "OK" : "ERROR"));

        result = p1.or(p.or(p2)).negate().test(); // false
        System.out.println(result + " expected : " + false + " : " + ((result==false) ? "OK" : "ERROR"));

    }

}
```

Comment: it looks like all your predicates should be of the type Order....

Comment: What is the question/problem here?

Comment: Implementation of Chaining predicates and test them together.

Comment: is Order contains User and ManagerCompetency ?

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense to chain predicates of different types together - they eventually need to be evaluated against a *single* object.

Comment: Order contains User , but ManagerCompetency is Manager propery.

Comment: whats the connection between `Order` and `Manager`?  how are these classes related?

Comment: I assume `User` and `Manager` are contained within `Order`?

Comment: from your question, I can see you have done two things: does user can create order? is order expired and approved? so you should break it into 2 conditions, e.g: `boolean precondition = userCanCreateOrder && orderIsNotExpiredAndApprovedByManager`.

Comment: Im tryimg to avoid BigFat Order classes because there are can be too many facts and they did not inherited from Order class, like a environment , etc..

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  Сan you give me more explaination about "It doesn't really make any sense to chain predicates of different types together - they eventually need to be evaluated against a single object." ?

Comment: About predicate is ultimately just a function. One you've built your predicate (perhaps through chaining with `and` and `or`) that will be applied (somewhere in your code) to a single object of type T to produce a single Boolean result.

Answer (score 3):

As the method signatures suggest, you can only chain predicates of the same type. There is no workaround for this, unless your classes share the superclass.

```
Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other)

Predicate<T> or(Predicate<? super T> other)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are over-complicating things. Your `OrderAcceptanceSpecification` could just contain two methods:

```
 static class OrderAcceptanceSpecification {

    static Predicate<Order> isOrderApproved() {
        return Order::isApproved;
    }

    static Predicate<Order> isOrderExpiredAfter(int seconds) {
        return o -> System.nanoTime() - o.createdAt() > seconds;
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a class that looks like this:

```
 class Order {
    private final Manager manager;
    private final User user;
    ....
```

The `Predicate` that you need could be written like this:

```
Predicate<Order> predicate = OrderAcceptanceSpecification.isOrderApproved()
            .and(x -> x.getUser().isActive())
            .and(OrderAcceptanceSpecification.isOrderExpiredAfter(3600).negate())
            .and(x -> x.getManager().getCompetency().equals(ManagerCompetency.HIGH)
                    || x.getManager().getCompetency().equals(ManagerCompetency.MIDDLE));
```

I find the `||` cleaner than casting the lambda expression to a `Predicate` and chaining `or`.

Comment: In my vision OrderAcceptanceSpecification is set of predefined conditions, which used to verify availability to accept order , that`s why  isOrderApproverCompetentAs in OrderAcceptanceSpecification class.

Comment: @Anton.S you could have *at least* shown the structure of your classes, so that we would not guess

Comment: @Anton.S add that your question, not as a comment