# Is it possible to chain predicates with `and` using different type parameter?

Tags: java, java-8, generic-lambda

I am learning Java 8 lambdas. Can I join two predicates, with different type parameter, using and method in Predicate interface?

This is my code:

```
Predicate<Integer> pc = (iv) -> iv > 20;
Predicate<String> pL = (is) -> is.length() > 5;
System.out.println("The predicate result for pc is: " + pc.test(25));
System.out.println("===========");
System.out.println("The predicate result with both condition true: " + pc.and(pL.test("abcd")));
```

Comment: Depends on what actually are you trying to achieve there might be alternatives. You cannot chain then specifically since they are defined to be on different types. The signature of `and` would help understand that.

Comment: @Naman thanks man, I just wanted to know that different type parameter will work for chaining using `and`. So I can't chain them with different types.

Comment: If the integer and string predicates correspond to properties of a class `T`, you could have a `Predicate<T>`

Comment: In your example, this should not work: pc.and(pL.test("abcd"))
To use and(predicate) method, you should chain predicates like this : predicate1.and(predicate2).and(predicate3).test(myVar)
But all predicates should be of the same type.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. `pL.test("abcd")` returns a boolean, but `and` expects a *predicate*. (`incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to Predicate<? super Integer>`).

Comment: That should be a hint for you, looking at the expected types and the error messages...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement predicate chaining based on different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711123/implement-predicate-chaining-based-on-different-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not chain predicates of different types, unless the chained *predicate* also accepts the type of the original predicate.

Looking at the signature, you can easily see that:
`and(Predicate<? super T> other)`
`or(Predicate<? super T> other)`

You can chain predicates:

```java
Predicate<Person> isMale = p -> p.isMale();
Predicate<Person> isAdult = p -> p.age() >= AGE_OF_MATURITY;
Predicate<Person> isAdultMale = isAdult.and(isMale);
```

You can only chain predicates that accept *at least* (thats what the `? super T` says) the same type as the original predicate:

```java
Predicate<Object> hasWeirdHashCode = o -> o.hashCode() == 0;
Predicate<Person> nonsense = isMale.and(hasWeirdHashCode);
```

If you want to test different types (`A`, `B`), you need to provide them separately:

```java
Predicate<A> propertyOfA = [...];
Predicate<B> propertyOfB = [...];

BiPredicate<A,B> propertyOfAnB = (a, b) -> 
    propertyOfA.test(a) && propertyOfB.test(b);
```

If you need more than two different types, you need to roll your own, custom `TriPredicate`, `QuadPredicate` and so on functional interfaces, which should be straight-forward to implement.

Comment: This is a very good and thorough answer. Just a note on your final comment... An alternative to create your own `Tri`, `Quad` etc functional interfaces would be to use *currying*, i.e. `Function<A, Function<B, Predicate<C>>> triPred = a -> b -> c -> propertyOfA.test(a) && propertyOfB.test(b) && propertyOfC.test(c)`, assuming you have previously declared such predicates

Comment: @fps I avoided currying for the same reason I used `Predicate` and not `Function<T, Boolean>`: Java places quite some importance on names, and I really don't want to explain more functional concepts like currying, type normalization, binding, etc. in this answer.

Comment: Yes, Java's type system makes it horrible to use currying, because of generics dreadful verbosity and ugly syntax. That's why I upvoted and just left a comment :)

Comment: @fps Its one of my dreams that after Valhalla, Panama and Leyden, maybe lambdas are re-visited at some point. Having functions as first-class citizens would be a *vast* improvement for Java... but I highly doubt we'll see that within the next 10 years.

Comment: Functions as first-class citizens is just a dream...